# Bash variable with newlines not being represented correctly within csv file

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I'm trying to stick the text output of a linux command into a single cell of a csv file. No matter how I try to escape quotes, the newline characters do not seem to be registered by the csv file.

For example if the output of one of these commands is:

```
155 C T
2518 T C
```

It is being printed within the csv cell as:

```
155 C T 2518 T C
```

```
for filename in "$1"/*JGI*.vcf; do
    counter=$((counter + 1))

    depth_score="$(samtools depth "${filename%.*}.bam" | python depth.py)"
    variant_array="$(bcftools query -f '%POS %REF %ALT\n' "$filename")"
    column_name="$(basename "$filename")"

    echo "$counter/$total_colonies" # echo current/total
    echo "$variant_array"
    echo ""$variant_array""
    echo "$column_name, "$variant_array", $depth_score" >> output.csv
done
```

Here is the for loop that's giving me some errors.

The result of the `$variant_array` is the problem.

I have two print logs above where I write to the output.csv to see what's going on.

`"$variant_array"` yields the desired behavior, but for some reason when I echo that within another set of quotes to write it to the csv file, it ignores the newlines...

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes do not escape this way... So perhaps the following will work for you?

```
echo '"'"$variant_array"'"'
echo "$column_name", '"'"$variant_array"'"', "$depth_score" >> output.csv
```

Here is another form of escaping quotes:

```
echo \""$variant_array"\"
echo "$column_name", \""$variant_array"\", "$depth_score" >> output.csv
```

Here is another idea:

```
echo "\"$variant_array\""
echo "$column_name, \"$variant_array\", $depth_score" >> output.csv
```

Comment: Good point.  In a CSV file, the OP probably does want double-quotes to appear in the output.

Comment: Possibly simpler: `echo "\"$variant_array\""`

Comment: Both the second two were perfect solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$variant_array` is **not** "within another set of quotes."  It is entirely unquoted.

Replace:

```
echo "$column_name, "$variant_array", $depth_score" >> output.csv
```

with:

```
echo "$column_name", "$variant_array", "$depth_score" >> output.csv
```

or, simpler still:

```
echo "$column_name, $variant_array, $depth_score" >> output.csv
```

Comment: It happens to all of us at one time or another.